# 30 points in the plane 12 red segments and 17 blue segments from each point

Tags: combinatorics, coloring, extremal-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Given 30 points in the plane no 3 of which are collinear, we color the segments formed by the pairs of these points red and blue such that: from every point there emerge 12 red segments and 17 blue segments.
How many triangles that have all three sides of the same colour are there?

N.B. i think the phrasing of the problem is bad - the number of monochromatic triangles surely cannot be constant right? However it’s rather hard for me to construct two examples with a different number of triangles. Maybe the problem wanted the minimum number of such triangles

Comment: Your title says "12 blue segments and 19 (then 17) red segments from each point" while your question says " from every point there emerge 12 red segments and 17 blue segments".  Your first edit still mixed up red and blue.  When you edit your question to tidy this up, could you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: This is more interesting than I thought at first.

Comment: Look at this article by
[G. Lorden, Blue-empty chromatic graphs, Amer. Math. monthly 69 (1962) 114-119](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1962.11989845).

Comment: So do you guys think that in general the number of monochratic triangles is not constant and that maybe the author of the problem meant the minimum number of such triangles @ kabenyuk? Also can we prove this with an example maybe?

Comment: Lemma 1 in the linked paper implies that the number of monochromatic triangles is constant and equal to 1000.

Comment: Sorry guys but how do I access that article?

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2312538.pdf?casa_token=R7P8nsn4BucAAAAA:qA-M7B6B2KM1NP2T3hZ5faZJblRmEGOb2Dit0xQJ-Agdy2ABTsTaQVEzqKWze9w6KdDA4kp-9Id-RZZaEDIHse2UpzKRgERdFDdDLDeA4oTZY3SR_cFV

Comment: Thank you! Question can then be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma 1 in the Lorden paper shows that if node $i$ has $r_i$ red incident edges and $n-1-r_i$ blue incident edges, the number of monochromatic triangles is
$$\binom{n}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n r_i (n-1-r_i).$$
For $n=30$ and $r_i=12$ for all $i$, this formula yields
$$\binom{30}{3}-\frac{30 \cdot 12 \cdot 17}{2} = 4060 - 3060 = 1000$$
monochromatic triangles